# Is my Godeps.json correctly generated?

Tags: heroku, go

I am trying to deploy a simple go lang server on heroku.I have managed to get it running. But I am wondering if my utilisation of godep is proper.

Here is the Godeps.json I have produced.

```
{
    "ImportPath": ".",
    "GoVersion": "go1.5",
    "Packages": [
        "./..."
    ],
    "Deps": [
        {
            "ImportPath": "github.com/kevinlg/trendee-api",
            "Rev": "6acde53081a273d4caedf113688e1ab83854c877"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am wondering why "ImportPath":"." and not github.com/kevinlg/trendee-api instead of having it as a dependency ?

When I check the Heroku example or the Godeps.json for godep I can see

"ImportPath": "github.com/heroku/go-getting-started",

or

"ImportPath": "github.com/tools/godep

I have been able to get the server running and deployed on heroku.

Here is my project folder structure

```
trendee-api /(GOPATH)
   bin/
   Godeps/
   pkg/
   src/
     github.com/
      kevinlg/
        trendee-api/
```

I have used the following commands.

```
godep save -r ./...
go install github.com/kevinlg/trendee-api
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `godep save -r ./...` you are saving [multiple packages](https://github.com/tools/godep#multiple-packages), which is why your `Godeps.json` looks like that.

For a single binary, you could also use `godep save -r` in the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/kevinlg/trendee-api` directory, given the following structure:

`trendee-api /(GOPATH)
   bin/
   Godeps/
   pkg/
   src/
     github.com/
      kevinlg/
        trendee-api/
            main.go`

Comment: If I use godep save -r  then the Godeps.json become {
 "ImportPath": ".",
 "GoVersion": "go1.5",
 "Deps": []
}   And deployement to heroku does not work anymore. I am a bit in the flu regarding the godep behavior

Comment: Where is your `main.go` located? In which directory are you running `godep save`?

Comment: My main.go is located in the trendee/api/src/github.com/kevinlg/trendee-api/ I run godep save from trendee-api (GOPATH) the root of my workspace.

Comment: That's your problem. You need to run it from inside `trendee/api/src/github.com/kevinlg/trendee-api/`.

Comment: Yes I am going to try it I have checked the herkou example again. I forgot the ./.... in the go get command. So I did not see the full structure of the example before. Now that I see it it appear clear to me. But I am not a really big fan of having the Godeps file member of the /src/.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the good path. I had one problems I was not executing the godep save command from the good folder you need to execute in the $GOPATH/src/github.com/username/your_project Second one I forgot to add  the ./... go get command when I tried the heroku tutorial. I will put a medium post together about how to use godep with heroku. I will insist on where to execute each commande and why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to go and I had problem with Godeps too.
why you are using "go install ".
try using this link,
[this is the heroku's website teaching about Godeps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-dependencies-via-godep)

and actually you can use `godep help save`
 in command line to learn more about "godep save"

Comment: I checked my own "Godeps.json" file  and the diff between mine and yours is just at the ' "ImportPath": ' at the top of the file. I can suggest you to try the heroku's support .